# Evaluate $\int\sqrt{x^2+6x} \;dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals, substitution

**Evaluate $\large\int\sqrt{x^2+6x} \;dx$**

I am having trouble with this problem and don't understand why my answer is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: Notice that $\sec\theta=\frac{x+3}{3}$ and $\tan\theta=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+6x}}{3}$.

Comment: Try formatting your posts with $\LaTeX$. Here are some tips: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264.

Comment: What a lovely handwriting !!!